# Reading messages from kafka and join all of them in the last minute using rxjava

Tags: java, apache-kafka, rx-java

How would I concatenate messages for one minute received from kafkaProducer

Comment: Or at least an approach how to implement it

Comment: Please show your attempts so far

Comment: Also not clear what "last minute" means. Rxjava doesn't expose the concept of timeslice

Comment: This is like an intention. Firstly need to understand wether it is possible to implement it using rxjava...

Comment: @OneCricketeer for example the message has been consumed by Kafka consumer and then since that time we need to countdown one minute and get all of them and put in one slice... and continue slicing messages by one minute interval...

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible on rxjava. Seems you're asking for sliding windows in Kafka Stearms, though, which has an API similar to rx

Comment: @OneCricketeer so you are suggesting to use Kafka streams?

Comment: That allows logic similar to what you want, sounds like.

Comment: @OneCricketeer got it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#windowing